# Creating a shar with pre & post script

Tags: bash

Any tips of how to make sure the post script runs ?
I have a pre & post shell script which I append befor and after the shar file, what happens is that the post script which is supposed to extract my tar doesn't execute.
So I have done the following:

1. Created Pre.sh & post.sh
2. Created a create shar script which does:

   ```
   cat Pre.sh > $sharfile
   shar my.tar.gz >> $sharfile 
   cat Post.sh >> $sharfile
   ```

The create shar has a first arg of the tar.gz name so basically I can control what tar I'm passing to the create_shar script.

For debugging I put set -x in the Pre script but the output just terminates just after unpacking (not extracting ) the tar into the current dir, then it exits.

Must be something very simple I am missing here ...

Answer (score 1):

First, use shar to pack a file, any file. Don't use any redirection so that you see the commands on the standard output. Note that the last line that you see is `exit 0`. This is what is causing your compound script to exit after unpacking `my.tar.gz`.

How to fix:

```
cat Pre.sh > $sharfile
shar my.tar.gz | sed '/^exit 0/d' >> $sharfile 
cat Post.sh >> $sharfile
```

This removes the last line that starts with `exit 0` from the shar, and allows the Post.sh script to run.